# Distinguish directed and undirected graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I need to write a graph using C++ and I have a little problem. My graph should be directed or undirected, weighted or unweighted, based on matrix or list all on user's choice. And distinguishing matrix from list graph is not a big deal, since it's two different classes, I got some problem with other parameters. The most obvious way to distinguish them is to make two `bool` variables and check them on every adding and deleting of vertex. It is quite obvious and easy to understand, but I doubt it's efficiency, because every time I add or delete vertex I have to do additional `if`. I also could write subclasses for it, but I seriously doubt if it's worth it.

Every library is okay to use, if it's not representing graph itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For directed and undirected best case is using bool variable for your graph, however You can assume your graph is weighted and directed, but for undirected edges add one edge from a→b and one edge from b→a. Also if there isn't weight function set its weight to `1`.

But if you looking for graph library it depends to your programming language, but I'd suggest [graph boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) which implemented fully in c++, and too many other people implement it partially in other languages.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use bool variable then.